# Retrofit response cannot handle space

Tags: android, retrofit

I am using retrofit on android to communicate with server with `Call<String>` from retrofit, and then in php i echo a string with space for example `echo "aaa bbb"`, and then the retrofit response body is "aaa". What should i do to get the full string "aaa bbb"?

Comment: please post log, api output and your retrofit call

Comment: 1. Call<String>
2. echo "tidak bisa absen lagi"
3. response "tidak"

Comment: show your api output like this https://s3.amazonaws.com/postman-static-getpostman-com/postman-docs/58538745.png

Comment: {"tidak bisa absen lagi"}

Comment: then can you show me image what is problem with it ?

Comment: it is not {"tidak bisa absen lagi"} but tidak bisa absen lagi, without " and {, }

Comment: if your using retrofit then you need to put it in Json Array

Comment: but i am using Call<String> from retrofit

Comment: Please check someone question of retrofit call cause your not providing enough information

Comment: and then from php, i just echo a string with space

Comment: i edit my question